# How can I use `TRIM` while sorting on a Group_Concat column?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query that looks similar to the following

```
SELECT
    ta.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(tb.value) AS `grouped_value`
FROM
     test.test_a ta
INNER JOIN test.test_b tb ON tb.id = ta.t_id
GROUP BY ta.t_id
ORDER BY `grouped_value` ASC
```

I am using the `GROUP_CONCAT` function to create a comma-separated value, aliased as `grouped_value`. The query above works as it should, but `grouped_value` may contain leading space and messes with sorting of the final results. I attempted to use the `TRIM` function, but that does not appear to work in this instance.

```
SELECT
        ta.*,
        GROUP_CONCAT(tb.value) AS `grouped_value`
FROM
    test.test_a ta
INNER JOIN test.test_b tb ON tb.id = ta.t_id
GROUP BY ta.t_id
ORDER BY TRIM(`grouped_value`) ASC
```

**Error Message**

> Error Code: 1247 - Reference 'grouped_value' not supported (reference to group function)

Is it possible to use `TRIM` while sorting on a group concatenated column? If not, what is a work around for this error?

Comment: Why are you using an aggregate function, `GROUP_CONCAT()`, without using `GROUP BY`?  What output do you really want?  Your current query doesn't seem meaningful.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I added the `GROUP BY`, it appears I missed it while writing the question

Comment: Trim before grouping? `GROUP_CONCAT(trim(tb.value)) as grouped_value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to trim each of the individual values in your list. In that case place it inside the `GROUP_CONCAT` call:

```
SELECT
    ta.*,
    GROUP_CONCAT(TRIM(tb.value)) AS grouped_value
FROM
     test.test_a ta
INNER JOIN test.test_b tb ON tb.id = ta.t_id
GROUP BY ta.t_id
ORDER BY grouped_value ASC
```

As discussed in comments, if you need to keep the white-space in the displayed values, then you would just do the trimming in the `order by` clause:

```
ORDER BY GROUP_CONCAT(TRIM(tb.value)) ASC
```

Comment: And if you need the whitespaces for display purpose, use a second column, dedicated for sorting (trimmed) and one (untrimmed) to be displayed.

Comment: @dognose I do need to keep the whitespaces, which is why I was using the `trim` on the sort rather than the `group_concat`. Adding your suggestion to the answer will do as a workaround

Answer (score 0):

You are uing a aggegatioin function without group by  ( and you should esplicitally set the column name in select and group by ) 
eg:  assuming you have col1 and col2 from ta yous should

```
SELECT
    ta.col1, ta.col2,
    GROUP_CONCAT(tb.value) AS `grouped_value`
FROM
     test.test_a ta
INNER JOIN test.test_b tb ON tb.id = ta.t_id
GROUP BY ta.col1, ta.col2,
ORDER BY `grouped_value` ASC
```

anf for trim  simple apply to result

```
SELECT
    ta.col1, ta.col2,
    trim(GROUP_CONCAT(tb.value)) AS `grouped_value`
FROM
     test.test_a ta
INNER JOIN test.test_b tb ON tb.id = ta.t_id
GROUP BY ta.col1, ta.col2,
ORDER BY `grouped_value` ASC
```